# Spring Setup not working

Tags: spring, jsp, web-applications

I cant get Spring-Web to work.

1. My pom.xml has dependencys to spring-web and spring-webmvc.
2. My web.xml has `<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>`
3. applicationContext.xml defines a bean "test"
4. My index.jsp try to get the Context via RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(request);

But i get a Exception instead:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: not in a DispatcherServlet request?
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(RequestContextUtils.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(RequestContextUtils.java:60)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:65)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

This is my whole full web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app version="3.0">
  <listeners>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listeners>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Are you using Springs `DispatcherServlet` in your deployment descriptor?  As far as I can tell, from the stacktrace it is suggesting that you are not, and that is an important part of getting Spring to work in a web environment.

Comment: Ok, well, you need to :)

Comment: iv bound the servlet to *.jsp but he like to have a ...-servlet.xml. This is webmvc right? Can i get rid of webmvc and use spring web only?

Comment: you should define <servlet/> and <servlet-mapping/> in your web.xml...

Comment: @Jaiwo99 please read my last comment.

Comment: if you are not using spring-mvc, you don't have to include spring-webmvc in your project. maybe you can post your web.xml...

Comment: Then i need a replacement for RequestContextUtils that is part of spring-mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get Rid of spring-mvc like @Jaiwo99 sais. Spring-Web works great without Spring-MVC.
2. Use `WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(application)`
   instead of 
   `RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(request)`.

Comment: Session-Beans and Request-Beans must have a second listener-class `RequestContextListener`